# How to update an object element in array with specific index, React State

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

The code below is what I'm trying to do update main_id and sub_ids in the state.

I got stucked from here...

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
    ids: [
      {
        main_id: null,
        sub_ids: []
      }
    ]
  });

//this is what I've tried..
const handleState = index => (v) => {
  setState({...setState, ids: setState.ids.map((x,i)=>(
      i === index ? {x.main_id: v.id, sub_ids: []})

    ))})
}
```

I'm using this function on same component which means it adds in specific index of array with different object.

```
<componentOne onChange ={handleState(k)}/>
<componentTwo onChange={handlestate(k)} />
```

The state that I desired to get after this,

```
state ={
ids:[
      {
     main_id: v.id,
     sub_ids:[]
      },
      {
     main_id: v.id,
     sub_ids:[]
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to spread in your state updater function (`setState`) versus your current state object (`state`).

Shallow copy existing state, then also shallow copy the element when the index matches. You should also use a functional state update.

```
const handleState = index => v => {
  setState(state => ({
    ...state, // <-- copy previous state
    ids: state.ids.map((x, i) =>
      i === index
        ? {
            ...x, // <-- on match, copy element, then update properties
            main_id: v.id,
            sub_ids: [],
          }
        : x, // <-- non-match, just pass element through
    ),
  }));
};
```

It may be a little clearer to simplify your state though since it appears you overwrite the entire element object.

```
const [ids, setIds] = useState([
  {
    main_id: null,
    sub_ids: []
  }
]);

const handleState = index => v => {
  setIds(ids => ids.map((x, i) =>
      i === index
        ? {
            main_id: v.id,
            sub_ids: [],
          }
        : x,
    ),
  }));
};
```

Comment: Thank you, It works perfectly. But can I ask one more question. So I'm using this function for  other same component. What should I do if I want to add same structure of 'ids' on ext index  of it? I edited desired result

Comment: @HK Sorry, I don't quite follow the question. Are you asking how to append new "empty" entries into your state data?

Comment: I want to use this function on same component. components are currently generated by map function with index

Comment: @HK Ah, I see. Do both components render the same data in the same way? i.e. is the kindex `k` going to be the same for both? Or is all the same component, just different instances of it from the map function? It may be easier to just update your question to include a snippet of how you are mapping to components and attaching the `handleState` callback.

Comment: k is incremented by +1. And Yes, same component and similar data but different instances of it from the map function.

Comment: `setProjectState(state=>({ ...state,  labels[index]: state.labels.map((x,i)=> i===index ?{ ...x,   label_id: v.label_id,     }: x)}))` I tried this but looks like not working

Comment: @HK Ok, this looks to be a little out-of-scope for this question/issue and TBH it still isn't quite clear what you are asking about. If you are mapping data to components then they can all use the same curried callback handler. If you want to open a new SO issue feel free to (at)me here and I can take a look and dig deeper when I have a bit more time, but this way you can get more eyes on this other issue more quickly.